# UITableview grouped style only showing one value from array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

MY UITableview Group style only showing one value from the array of 4 elements.

in viewdidload i add following array

```
    _displayThemeItems=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Default",@"Night",@"Sepia" ,@"Blue" ,nil];
    _displayThemeIcons=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"day.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"night.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"sepia.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"],nil];
```

and my table delegate methods

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

      return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        return [_displayThemeItems count];


}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // No cell available - create one.
    if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
    NSLog(@"rray%@",_displayThemeItems);
    cell.textLabel.text = [_displayThemeItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image=[_displayThemeIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: where is the closing brace for if (cell == nil)?

Comment: that smy mistake i forget to add that brace here..in code its there

Comment: He did edit it 8 min ago.  It's after the `;` at the end of the cell allocation line.

Comment: Is your tableview in your XIB/Storyboard large enough to show 4 rows?

Comment: yes.its larger.but not displaying

Comment: Have you debugged to check how many times cellForRowAtIndexPath is called and what the indexes are? Is anything else editing (replacing) the array (the 'rray' log shows all items)? Is there other code in those methods that you didn't post?

Comment: Simply put an NSLog and print the array at various points in your program and you will see where its going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code look fine to me, the only the only reason that I can think amy effect the result you see is how you set up your table view.
Make sure that your table view frame is bug enough to show the 4 items, and make sure you set the tabe view data source.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "}" just before the return such that the code where you set the title and image comes under the "if" statement.